# Creating an MDE 2003 file from Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

I run MS Access 2010 on my home PC and I've been building a database for work.

Most workstations at work don't run Access to build databases, but they do allow us to run MDE files for applications already built.

I saved my database as a 2002-2003 database and then published it as an MDE file. All worked really well. I tested the MDE file on my PC at home and the automatic re-linking to the back end db worked and the database popped up. Awesome.

The problem came when I tried to run it on the workstation. It came up with an unrecognized format and suggest I change the version on the database.

So, back to the drawing board. I did some research and from all indications from other forums and sites, you cant build MDE files for 2002-2003 databases using Access 2007 or 2010, even though the option is clearly there.

Suggestions were to load Access 2003 to the PC an build the database using this. OK, did that, imported all of the items from the 2003 database created in Access 2010 to a blank db created in 2003 and I get nothing but errors. Incidentally the database was originally build from and access 2003 database at work! Unfortunately, I no longer have access to that particular workstation.

So that's the dilemma. The question / discussion im after is how to resolve this and get the database, preferably from my office 2010 suite into a standalone system of some type working from a Windows XP workstation at work.

I need to find a way to be able to build these tools at home and use them at work. BTW, upgrading the workstations at work is not an option. believe me the organisation is too large to even consider a change like that, WAY too much bureaucracy..

Comment: First, appropriately tag your question with `ms-access` (`mde` is a file extension of a software but you leave out the software). This will help others find your post. Second, is you backend database an accdb file? Change it to mdb. Publishing dbs in earlier format may not always work as several [compatibility issues](http://allenbrowne.com/access2007.html) arise. Create mdb in AC2003 and use your 2010 to update but simplify tables and forms.

Comment: Apologies for the incorrect tags. New on this board. I did not think to change the back end to an mde file. I will try that and see what happens.... Been playing with Filemaker as an alternative just in case. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Do your development with the oldest Office version any of your users will use.  In your case that means Office 2003, despite the fact that MS extended support for that version ended more than a year ago.  If installing Office 2003 on your home machine is not an option, consider a virtual machine or remote desktop session to a machine at work.

Comment: I personally would save it as a 2007 mde file and just have the users install access runtime 2007. (which is free and runs 2003 mde files).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments to your question, if you are targeting an older version of Access then you should be doing your development in that version, not a newer one. Even though Access 2010 allows us to create an .mde file that is in the Access 2003 file *format*, it may actually create an .mde file that Access 2003 cannot understand due to the *contents* of the file.

The situation is analogous to the problem of making certain modifications to an Access 2007 database in Access 2010+ that render it unusable by Access 2007. Even though the file *format* is still "Access 2007 or later", Access 2010 may create database *objects* within that file that Access 2007 cannot comprehend. Depending on the actual objects involved, Access 2007 may simply ignore what it doesn't understand, but unfortunately in some cases Access 2007 will just give up and say "Unrecognized database format".